# adding data from a string to binary tree using recursion java

Tags: java, string, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to basically add data to a binary tree where each node will contain a digit and number of times it has been entered. So example 1 1 2 2 lets say first node will have digit 1 and has been entered 2 times. Thats no problem. The issue I cant seem to understand is why does the count method seem to return right amount of occurences(2 times) for digit 1 but for digit 2 it gives me 4 occurences. Disregard the NullPointer handling in registerDigit, its just because if a node is not found the findNode method will return null, so it means I can add this node, once it is found then it shouldnt be added. Ofcourse in the beginning the tree is empty so the it will initially give me this error.

```
private void registerDigit(){
    System.out.println("Register digits like this: 1 2 3 4 1 4 ");
    values=input.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s","");

    for(int x=0; x<values.length();x++) {
        try{
            if(theTree.findNode(Integer.parseInt("" +  values.charAt(x)))==null )
                theTree.addNode(Integer.parseInt("" + values.charAt(x)),count(values,values.charAt(x)));
            else
                System.out.println("Digit "+values.charAt(x)+" has been added before with "+count(values,values.charAt(x))+ "times");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
        theTree.addNode(Integer.parseInt("" + values.charAt(x)),count(values,values.charAt(x)));
         }
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you, digits are registered");
}

public int count (String values, char c)
{
    int charOccurences=0;
    if(values.length()==0)
        return 0;
    if (values.contains(""+c))
        charOccurences++;
    else
        return 0;
    return charOccurences + count (values.substring(1), c);
}
```

Comment: can you please show us the output

Comment: this is wrong ! because you are searching in all string ,

Comment: for example if you have `1 1 2 2`
 when you are searching for 2 : first you are passing this String "1 1 2 2" this String contains 2 , then you are using substring method and String will be converted to this : `"1 2 2"` ---> `"2 2"` ---> `"2"` ----> `charOccurences = 4` !

Comment: ahaa, now I get it, thank you, I need to fix the count method

Comment: look your binary search tree must save all of the values , it doesn't matter how much times it happened . each node has a parent and left child and right child , the left child is less than or equal to his parent , the right child is greater than or equal to his parent , this is the rule of adding new node , it depends on your implementation , I think it was better if we could see your implementation of the tree

Comment: it is not necessary to use recursive method to count the occurrences , there are much better ways to calculate them easily

Comment: I was thinking about first sorting the string into an sorted array and then using a binary search to count occurances

Comment: but the assignment requirements is that there should not be two nodes with the same digit in the tree so I cant add nodes with digit 1 two times

Comment: define a class , name it node , it has two attributes , int value , int count

Comment: if a value exists in your data , increment its count , otherwise add it into your tree

Comment: this is an assignment ... :|